# How to prevent multiple binding to the same selector in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$(".post").on("click",show_hide_posts);

 //Callback function from third-party ajax plugin
 $.fn.almComplete = function(alm){

      $(".post").on("click",show_hide_posts);

 }
```

When document.ready I bind click to .post. When more content is loaded via ajax I use a callback function to bind new posts. This makes the old posts not work properly.

show_hide_posts has a simple hasClass to check whether the post should be visible/hidden on click. After the new posts are loaded, this hasClass check fails on the old posts, but still works on the new posts.

```
function show_hide_posts(){

e.preventDefault();

if(!$(this).hasClass('closed')){

   //hide post
   $(this).addClass("closed");

}else{

   //show post
   $(this).removeClass("closed");

}

}
```

I this behavior a result of biding the same selector more than once? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: You could use `.off()` to remove all the handlers before you bind yours.

Comment: Use event delegation? That way you don't have to re-bind it every time you add more content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I this behavior a result of biding the same selector more than once? Or am I missing something else?

Yes you are binding more than once.

Suppose you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="posts">
  <div class="post">A</post>
  <div class="post">B</post>
</div>
```

You call

```
$(".post").on("click",show_hide_posts);
```

So now `A` and `B` have a click handler.  You then ajax/update the html to be:

```
<div class="posts">
  <div class="post">A</post>
  <div class="post">B</post>
  <div class="post">C</post>
  <div class="post">D</post>
</div>
```

and call:

```
$(".post").on("click",show_hide_posts);
```

Now `A` and `B` have two handlers, while `C` and `D` have one.

> When document.ready I bind click to .post. When more content is loaded via ajax I use a callback function to bind new posts. This makes the old posts not work properly.

Correct, so the solution is not to bind to `.post` directly:

```
$('.posts').on('click', '.post', show_hide_posts);
```

This works for any number of dynamically added posts, and all `.post` within `.posts` have a single handler, and is never needed to be called again.

*Misc Notes*:

You most likely should not be doing:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This can cause quite a number of problems.

You can also replace:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('closed')){
  $(this).addClass("closed");
}else{
  $(this).removeClass("closed");
}
```

with:

```
$(this).toggleClass("closed");
```

Comment: Geez, did  I flub this one. This is obviously the right answer.

Comment: Although @Victor answer also works, this seems a lot more logical then binding and unbinding everytime more posts are loaded. Why should I not use e.preventDefault()?

Comment: Unless you are binding to an anchor (`<a href=""></a>`) it's not really needed.

Answer (score -1):

You are right, you shouldn't use a wide-ranging event handler when an object is already attached. Only wire up click events only for the newly created objects, or turn off the handler for existing objects with .off and reattach with .on

Comment: Attaching events to .post will not apply that event to objects that aren't rendered.

Answer (score -1):

If using jQuery 1.7+:

```
$('.post').off('click', show_hide_posts) // remove handler
          .on('click', show_hide_posts); // add handler
```

if not:

```
$('.post').unbind('click', show_hide_posts) // remove handler
          .bind('click', show_hide_posts); // add handler
```

Edit:
In cases like that i like to use livequery, take a look [here](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery).

```
$('.post').livequery(function () {
    $(this).on('click', show_hide_posts);
})
```

Comment: I used livequery a long time ago, I didn't think it was needed on the newest versions of jquery.

Comment: I would think that you should be binding these objects as they are added. Your ajax returns data, you construct the markup with data, assign it to a variable, append the variable, add click event to variable. That's typically how I do it.